# Android platform makefile (Android.bp), how to use kotlin @Parcelize annotation to create aidl files?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source, aidl, parceler

I am trying to use kotlin android extensions plugin Parcelize on Android platform.

I am on Kotlin 1.3.72.

I generated successfully a unitary dumb Rect.java without the plugin (by implementing parcelable methods manually) BUT this is kind of annoying to do it for lots of aidl objects especially since Kotlin has a code gen plugin to do it automatically for you.

I got the following error when using @Parcelize annotation:

> error: class 'Rect' is not abstract and does not implement abstract
> member public abstract fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel!, flags: Int):
> Unit defined in android.os.Parcelable

Can you told me where I am wrong?

Following class Rect with (working) and without (not working) annotation, and the Android.bp file:

> ```
> import android.os.Parcel
> import android.os.Parcelable
>
> class Rect() : Parcelable {
>     var left: Int = 0
>     var top: Int = 0
>     var right: Int = 0
>     var bottom: Int = 0
>
>     companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Rect> {
>         override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Rect {
>             return Rect(parcel)
>         }
>
>         override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Rect> {
>             return Array(size) { Rect() }
>         }
>     }
>
>     private constructor(inParcel: Parcel) : this() {
>         readFromParcel(inParcel)
>     }
>
>     override fun writeToParcel(outParcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
>         outParcel.writeInt(left)
>         outParcel.writeInt(top)
>         outParcel.writeInt(right)
>         outParcel.writeInt(bottom)
>     }
>
>     private fun readFromParcel(inParcel: Parcel) {
>         left = inParcel.readInt()
>         top = inParcel.readInt()
>         right = inParcel.readInt()
>         bottom = inParcel.readInt()
>     }
>
>     override fun describeContents(): Int {
>         return 0
>     }
> }
> ```

---

> ```
> import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
> import android.os.Parcelable
>
> @Parcelize
> class Rect() : Parcelable {
>     var left: Int = 0
>     var top: Int = 0
>     var right: Int = 0
>     var bottom: Int = 0
> }
> ```

---

> ```
> java_library {
>     name: "my_module",
>     srcs: ["src/main/java/**/*.java", "src/main/java/**/*.kt", "src/main/aidl/**/I*.aidl"],
>     java_version: "1.8",
>     aidl: {
>         local_include_dirs: ["src/main/aidl"],
>     },
>     static_libs: [
>         "kotlin-android-extensions"
>     ],
> }
>
>
> java_import {
>     name: "trove4j",
>     jars: ["trove4j-1.0.20200330.jar"],
>     host_supported: true,
>     sdk_version: "current",
> }
>
> java_import {
>     name: "kotlin-daemon-embeddable",
>     jars: ["kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar"],
>     host_supported: true,
>     sdk_version: "current",
> }
>
> java_import {
>     name: "kotlin-script-runtime",
>     jars: ["kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.72.jar"],
>     host_supported: true,
>     sdk_version: "current",
> }
>
> java_import {
>     name: "kotlin-compiler-embeddable",
>     jars: ["kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.72.jar"],
>     libs: ["kotlin-stdlib", "kotlin-reflect", "kotlin-script-runtime", "kotlin-daemon-embeddable", "trove4j"],
>     host_supported: true,
>     sdk_version: "current",
> }
>
> java_import {
>     name: "kotlin-android-extensions",
>     jars: ["kotlin-android-extensions-1.3.72.jar"],
>     libs: ["kotlin-compiler-embeddable"],
>     host_supported: true,
>     sdk_version: "current",
> }
> ```

Comment: I want to use kotlin-android-extensions in AOSP too. Did you find out how to do so?